# CSS - not scrollable in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile

I created a lightbox with a dialog box inside of it. The lightbox has a position fixed. Furthermore I hide the overflow of the webpage behind in order to reduce the height of the lightbox. If the height of the nested dialog box gets to large, I want vertical scrollbars for the dialog box. It works fine in the desktop browser, but on mobile I have no vertical scrollbars for the dialog and its content is not scrollable, why?

**[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5uggp6r/1/)**

HTML

```
<div class="lightbox">
<div class="dialog"><h4>Headline</h4>

    <p>
        ...</p>
</div>
```

```
 <h2> Website content</h2>
 <p>...</p>
```

CSS

```
body{
background: red;
padding: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.lightbox{
background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.dialog{
 width: 300px;
background: lightgrey;
padding: 20px;
margin: 50px auto;
color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: auto;
max-height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Try iScroll Js, It Works with both desktop and mobile device, If browser not supported then default scroll bar work. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5  Demo -> http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/  This also enable you to use touch and scroll for mobile devices

Comment: And Which lightbox plugin/Jquery you use ?

Comment: Here Is Demo Link http://jsfiddle.net/PPtWs/